# Can I use and store a value (int/string/object) in a Pin in anything other than Label, Adress and Bindingcontext?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use these now with other values and I need 1 more slot to store a value (int, object, string) in my Pin. I know you can make a custom pin etc and store extra value but to save time (if it is possible) it would be much easier for my code if one extra slot was available on the Pin to store something into.

```
             pin.Label = info1String;
             pin.Address = info2String;
             pin.BindingContext = info3String;
```

and I need to store info4String as well on my pin. Are there any "spot" left on the pin to store a value or are the ones i used above the only ones? If not I will have to make a custompin.

Update:

```
Dictionary<string,string> data = new Dictionary<string,string>();

private async Task<List<Pin>> LoadData() 
{
var pins = new List<Pin> ();

var getItems = await phpApi.getInfo ();

data.Add("info3", phoneString);
data.Add("info4", urlString);

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {


    nameString = currentItem ["name"].ToString (); 
    adressString = currentItem ["adress"].ToString (); 
    phoneString = currentItem ["phone"].ToString (); 
    urlString = currentItem ["URL"].ToString (); 

                var pin = new Pin ();
                pin.Label = nameString;
                pin.Address = adressString;
                pin.BindingContext = data;
                pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;
                pins.Add (pin);

    }
}

void onButtonClicked1 (object s, EventArgs a)
    {
        Pin pin = (Pin)s;
    Dictionary<string,string> myData = (Dictionary<string,string>) pin.BindingContext;
        Navigation.PushModalAsync (new DetailPage(myData["info3"], myData["info4"] ));

    }

public DetailPage (object theInfo, object theInfo2)
{
labelOne.text = theInfo;
labelTwo.text = theInfo2;
}
```

Comment: BindingContext can be any complex object - so you could store a Dictionary, List, Tuple, custom class, etc.   Or you could create a wrapper container as explained in your other questions.

Comment: so: `List<Object> objectList = new List<Object>();` and `objectList.Add (theID + theDescription);` and `pin.BindingContext = objectList;` when I try to filter that value `((string)p.BindingContext).Contains(filter))` it gives me an error: `Specified cast is not valid.` and On the next page where I push the bindingcontext i see the theID (which is a string) as `System.Collections.Generic.List 1`. Instead of just `1`

Comment: Do I need to for exmaple in the page that I push to from the pin and push with me an ID. public DetailPage (object binding){
myText = Description.ToString (); //and add a [1] or something like that?
}

Comment: If you assign a List<object> to BindingContext, you can't cast it to a string when you pull it out.  The wrapper container discussed in previous questions is a much better approach, I'm not sure why you're so reluctant to use it.

Comment: Because I have a filter, 5 different lists and if i change it to that "hell would break lose" yeah u know what i mean. I will do that when I start up a fresh project. But with this project i just want to close it out.

Comment: I tried with a string just now, same error. And on the next page I get the System.Collections.Generic.List 1 as well.

Comment: How do I pull out the value from the list? pin.BindingContext[1]?

Comment: BindingContext is an object.  You need to cast it to whatever type was assigned to it, then retrieve the value from there.

Comment: Not quite sure what u mean, didnt i do that with the code i showcased above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat - this is not what BindingContext is intended for, and is not the best way to solve this problem.  But if you insist on trying it this way...

BindingContext is a object.  You can store anything in it, you just need to cast it back to the original type when retrieving it.

```
string info3String = "blah";
...
pin.BindingContext = info3String;
...
string myString = (string)pin.BindingContext;
```

or with a more complex object like Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,string> data = new Dictionary<string,string>();
data.Add("info3","foo");
data.Add("info4","bar");
...
pin.BindingContext = data;
...
// this part goes in your Click handler, which is where you want to get the data out again
Dictionary<string,string> myData = (Dictionary<string,string>) pin.BindingContext;
// myData["info3"] will contain "foo"
// myData["info4"] will contain "bar"
```

Comment: Not quite what I was asking for. You said I could put a list together with my pin.BindingContext with in my case two different strings. And how would I be able to take out each of the different strings in that list afterwards (for example) when I push the pin.Bindingcontext to the nextpage if a pin was clicked.

Comment: `data.Add ("one", theID);
        data.Add ("two", theDescription);` And i get this error when I add them into my LoadData function which contains the pins: `Type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position>' does not contain a member 'add' and the best extension method overload xamarin.forms.settersextensions.add ... .. xamarin.forms.bindableproperty, object requires an instance of type`

Comment: you extract the data out of the BindingContext in the click handler, and then pass each string to DetailPage.  Or you can pass the entire Dictionary to DetailPage, but you need to modify the constructor to use a Dictionary parameter

Comment: I still get the errors from these `data.Add("info3", phoneString);
    data.Add("info4", urlString);`

Comment: you need to declare a new instance of Dictionary for each Pin, not reuse the same one

Comment: 10 hours later when I managed to fix that problem, I removed the data.add functions from the foreach and put them beside my await phpapi.getinfo where I gather my dbinfo. I get an error though, this piece of code right here: `Dictionary<string,string> myData = (Dictionary<string,string>) pin.BindingContext;` //this gives me the error: Specified cast is not valid.


   `Navigation.PushModalAsync (new DetailPage(pin.Label, pin.Address, myData["theID"]));`

Comment: updated my post with how i have my current code, that gives me the error i mentioned above.